# Simplifying trigonometric functions in integral in order to convert integral into the Frullani integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm given this horrific integral
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\alpha\cos(\alpha x) + 2\beta\cos^2(\frac{\beta}{2}x) + 2\gamma\cos((\gamma - 1)x)\cos(x) - \beta}{x}\operatorname{d}x,$$
and I have to convert it to the Frullani integral, i.e.
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{f(ax) - f(bx)}{x}\operatorname{d}x.$$

I've tried many trigonometric expansions and identities, but I still can't find the way. What would be the correct way to do so?

Edit: I forget to add, that there is relation $\alpha + \beta + 2\gamma = 0$.

Comment: You need some relation between $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ to have convergence.

Comment: @mickep done, I'm sorry, forget to add.